# CouchDB Fauxton _replicator db: exclamation stating "This database has just X docs and Y deleted docs"

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0, fauxton

I am using `Fauxton on Apache CouchDB`, version `2.3.1`.

Next to the `# of Docs` field for my `_replicator` db, there is an exclamation point.  When I hover over it, it says: `This database has just 4 docs and 5 deleted docs`.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

> [image: Screenshot of exclamation]

The replicator DB does have 4 docs inside (`_design/_replicator` doc + 3 replication configs).

I can't find this warning mentioned in the CouchDB docs anywhere.  What does it mean, and is it a bad thing?

Comment: As this is not a programming question, it would be better to ask on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the database information ([see doc_del_count](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#get--db)).
Basically, when you delete a document, a tombstone is kept inside the database so the replication protocol can properly synchronize the documents.

You shouldn't have to worry about this. Once compacted, the tombstone only keep very minimal information which doesn't impact performance.

If for some reasons you need to get rid of the `_deleted` documents, you can either purge them or do a filtered replication on `_deleted` documents.

Comment: Does this mean that the size of the DB is not only based on the number of documents but also in the number of deleted documents?